# Autogenerating primary key with Room doesn´t work

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I´m trying to autogenerate an id for this class but when I create a new player this way it gives me an error like i didn´t initialize the id, but it is supposed to autogenerate it. Am I missing something?

My code is this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "player_table")

class Player(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
              @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val player: String,
              @ColumnInfo(name = "number") val number: String,
              @ColumnInfo(name = "position") val position: String) {
}

player = Player("Carlos", "13", "Forward")
```

But like I said it gives me an error because it´s trying to get Carlos as the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the declaration of `id` to the end of the field list and give it a [default of null](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/PrimaryKey):

```
class Player(@ColumnInfo(name = "name") val player: String,
              @ColumnInfo(name = "number") val number: String,
              @ColumnInfo(name = "position") val position: String,
              @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int? = null) {
}
```